# "Change modifier of 'frame' to 'static'" in Java

Tags: java, static, jframe

I'm being told by Eclipse to change the modifier of my string variable to static. I don't understand why. I think I'm declaring everything right but I'm not sure.
Here's my code. The problem is happening on both lines 12 and 13.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MainClass {


    Rectangle dot1 = new Rectangle(1,1), dot2 = new Rectangle(1,1);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pythagorean Theorem");


    public static void main (String[] args){

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

    }


}
```

Comment: `I'm being told by Eclipse to change the modifier of my string variable to static` -- Please understand that Java/Eclipse is *not* telling you this. Rather it is telling you that you cannot make a static reference to a non-static variable or method. That's a big difference. The reason this is important is so that you don't misinterpret the error as it's not telling you to make the variable static and neither are we.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `frame` as an instance variable, but using it as a static variable. There are two solutions to this:

1) You can change the modifier of frame to static

2) Create an instance of your class, like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    MainClass mc = new MainClass();
    mc.frame.setVisible(true);
    mc.frame.setSize(500, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`frame` is an instance variable of MainClass which means you need an instance of MainClass in order to access it.  A static variable belongs to the class and does not require an instance.  Generally speaking, you should be avoiding storing things statically as they are hard to modify and test.

Rather create an instance of MainClass in your main method and then access your frame inside an instance method.

```
public class MainClass {
    Rectangle dot1 = new Rectangle(1,1), dot2 = new Rectangle(1,1);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pythagorean Theorem");

    public void buildUI() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainClass().buildUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Notice that when working with Swing, when you create/touch UI components, you need to do that on the Event Dispatch Thread ([EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)) which is what the `invokeLater` does.

Comment: This isn't going to end well. Nothing is being done on the Event Dispatch Thread.